# Select unique count of rows referenced

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

**High level:**

I have checklists and checklists have checklist items. I want get the count of checklists that been completed. Specifically, checklists that have checklist items but that are all completed.

**Tables:**

```
Table "checklists"

|     Column   |          Type          |
+--------------+------------------------+
| id           | integer                |
| name         | character varying(255) |

Table "checklist_items"

|     Column   |          Type          |
+--------------+------------------------+
| id           | integer                |
| completed    | boolean                |
| name         | character varying(255) |
| checklist_id | integer                |
```

**Question:**
What query will give me the completed checklists count? Specifically, being careful to exclude checklists that have checklist items that are both complete and incomplete and checklist that have no checklist items.

**Tried so far:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT "checklists"."id")
  FROM "checklists"
INNER JOIN "checklist_items" ON "checklist_items"."checklist_id" = "checklists"."id"
  WHERE "checklist_items"."completed" = 't'
```

Problem with this question is that it does not exclude partially completed checklists.

Comment: Updated question to point out that checklists that are not referenced by any checklist items should be excluded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Faster, yet:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT i.checklist_id)
FROM   checklist_items i
LEFT   JOIN checklist_items i1 ON i1.checklist_id = i2.checklist_id
                              AND i.completed IS NOT TRUE
WHERE i.completed
AND   i1.checklist_id IS NULL;
```

This only collects checklists where a completed item exists.
And excludes those where another checklist_item exists that is not completed (`FALSE` or `NULL`).

Comment: Thanks as always Erwin. Sometimes I wonder how much of the Postgresql in the wild is actually derived from your answers on SO...

Comment: @AndrewHubbs: Sir, you seem to be a master of the art of flattery.

Answer (score 2):

The following does this using a subquery:

```
select COUNT(*)
from (select cl.id,
             SUM(case when cli.completed <> 't' or cli.completed is null then 1 else 0 end) as NumIncomplete
      from checklists cl join
           checklist_items cli
           ON cli.checklist_id = cl.id
      group by cl.id
     ) t
where NumIncomplete = 0
```

You can run the subquery to see how many incomplete items there are for each check list.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Your answer led me to a solution. The only change needed is a `GROUP BY cl.id` inside the sub select. Otherwise Postgres throws an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   (
         SELECT 1
         FROM checklist_items
         GROUP BY checklist_id
         HAVING bool_and(completed)
       ) as sq
```

Comment: +1 This is pretty elegant. However, the `HAVING` clause wouldn't work. `min(boolean_col)` is not implemented. Also, `= 't'` is just noise with the proper boolean type in Postgres. I took the liberty to update with a working `HAVING` clause. Feel free to roll back if you disagree.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: This is what comes of not testing the query - d'oh! Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming empty checklists are considered finished (though you can modify this to remove empty checklists as well).

```
SELECT checklists.id 
FROM checklists LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT checklist_id 
                           FROM checklist_items WHERE completed = 'f') partial_checklists 
                ON checklists.id = partial_checklists.checklist_id 
WHERE partial_checklists.checklist_id = NULL
```

To exclude empty checklists (though I'm not sure of the syntax here):

```
SELECT checklists.id 
FROM checklists LEFT JOIN (SELECT checklist_id 
                           FROM checklist_items WHERE completed = 'f' 
                         UNION DISTINCT 
                           SELECT checklist_id 
                           FROM checklist_items 
                           GROUP BY checklist_id 
                           HAVING count(*) = 0) partial_checklists 
                  ON checklists.id = partial_checklists.checklist_id 
WHERE partial_checklists.checklist_id = NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) completed_items
from (
    select
        c.id, c.name, count(*) total_items
    from
        checklists c
        inner join
        checklist_items ci on c.id = ci.checklist_id
    group by c.id, c.name
    having count(!completed or null) = 0
) s
```